# Flask with mod_wsgi - Cannot call my modules

Tags: python, flask, undefined, global, mod-wsgi

I have changed my application running with flask and python2.7 from a standalone solution to flask with apache and mod_wsgi.

My Flask app (app.py) includes some classes which are in the directory below my app dir (../).

Here is my app.wsgi:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr
    
    
    project_home = '/opt/appdir/Application/myapp'
    project_web  = '/opt/appdir/Application/myapp/web'
    
    
    if project_home not in sys.path:
        sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path
    
    if project_web not in sys.path:
        sys.path = [project_web] + sys.path
    
    from app import app
    application = app
```

Before my configuration to mod_wsgi my main call in the app.py looks like that:

```
    # Main
    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        from os import sys, path
        sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
        from logger import Logger
        from main import Main
        from configReader import ConfigReader
        print "Calling flask"
        from threadhandler import ThreadHandler
        ca = ConfigReader()
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", threaded=True)
```

I was perfectly able to load my classes in the directory below.
After running the app with mod_wsgi I get the following error:
global name \'Main\' is not defined

So how do I have to change my app that this here would work:

```
    @app.route("/")
    def test():
       main = Main("test")
       return main.responseMessage()
```

Comment: Have you tried to `import Main`in your app wsgi?

Comment: Nothing under that ``__main__`` check will be executed under mod_wsgi as your script isn't executed as a main script. Anything in that which sets up ``sys.path`` must be done in ``app.wsgi`` or better still in the Apache configuration for mod_wsgi. Anything else such as importing modules needs to always be done at the top of any code file needing them.

Answer (score 0):

No main function call with mod_wsgi was the right answer. I do not implemented my required modules in the wsgi file,
but on top of the flask app.